# how to work with button which is in div tag and u have to click without using xpath?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

This is the interview question asked to my friend for which i dont the answer. Please help me.

**Question:**
"how to work with button which is in div tag and u have to click
without using xpath?"

Thanks
Mahesh

Comment: I got confused like button is in Div tag, so i dint think of other possibilities like below answer. Sorry.. :(

Comment: can you give your html content where this button is located...?

Answer (score 1):

Use any other location strategy. The [`By`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/By.html) class offers you a whole lot more possibilities than only XPath. XPath expressions are the strongest possibility, but they are also very slow and tend to get veeeeryyyyy long sometimes.

1. id
2. name
3. tag name
4. class name
5. link text
6. partial link text
7. CSS selectors
8. XPath expressions

This, more or less, is the order of location strategies that you should use. Use `By.id()` any time you can. If you can't, use `By.name()` etc. They are ordered from the most concrete (and fast and simple) to the most broad (and slow and complex).

Pick any one that suits the particular context. In your case, look for an id, name, or use a CSS selector.

Comment: Thanks lot...:)

I got confused like button is in Div tag, so i dint think of other possibilities like below answer. Sorry.. :( –

Answer (score 0):

You can find your element by link text.

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(selector)).click();
```

using this code you can click on button without using **Xpath**.

Comment: I got confused like button is in Div tag, so i dint think of other possibilities like below answer. Sorry.. :( –